# How do I when I have more questions for same word in same context?Post a new question or edit origin question or other?

Tags: discussion

How do I when I have more questions for same word in same context?Post a new question or edit origin question or other?
For example :
origin question :[What is the regular kana text of the image?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56759/what-is-the-regular-kana-text-of-the-image)

question 1:`'もそっ' or 'もそ'　which should I do search in　dictionary ?`

question 2: `Is '`[もそっと](http://tangorin.com/general/%E3%82%82%E3%81%9D)`' more suitable in that context? it make-sense to me as 'Restless of wait a few minutes'(i.e Wait a little more time)`